# How to wait for the this.submit() function to be finished in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

**EDIT**

After Rory McCrossan's indication, I changed the code to get this:

```
var backNext = [
    {
        text: "&lt;",
        action: function (e) {

            this.submit( function () {

            }, null, null, false );

            table.on( 'draw', function () {
                var indexes = table.rows( {search: 'applied'} ).indexes();
                var currentIndex = table.row( {selected: true} ).index();
                var currentPosition = indexes.indexOf( currentIndex );                         

                if ( currentPosition > 0 ) {
                    var prev;
                    for (let i = currentPosition; i > 0; i--){
                        if(table.row(i-1).data()["Date"] === ""){
                            prev = i-1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(prev !== undefined){
                        table.row( currentIndex ).deselect();
                        table.row( indexes[ prev ] ).select();
                    }
                }

                // Trigger editing through the button
                table.button( 0 ).trigger();
            });        
        }
    },
    'Enregistrer',
    {
        text: "&gt;",
        action: function (e) {

            this.submit( function() {

            }, null, null, false );

            table.on( 'draw', function () {
                var currentIndex = table.row( {selected: true} ).index();
                var currentPosition = indexes.indexOf( currentIndex );
                var indexes = table.rows( {search: 'applied'} ).indexes();

                if ( currentPosition < indexes.length-1 ) {
                    var next = 0;
                    for (let i = currentPosition; i < indexes.length-1; i++){
                        if(table.row(i+1).data()["Date"] === ""){
                            next = i+1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (next !== 0){
                        table.row( currentIndex ).deselect();
                        table.row( indexes[ next ] ).select();
                    }
                }

                // Trigger editing through the button
                table.button( 0 ).trigger();
            });
        }
    }
];
```

It works, but the line `var currentPosition = indexes.indexOf( currentIndex );`  causes the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. I think it comes from the fact that the code is executed outside the context of this. So any help on solving this problem would be appreciated.

---

I am currently using the [previous / next editing](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/backNext.html) option of Datatables. The data is loaded from the server and sent by ajax. The peculiarity is that when editing data, the structure of the table may change (additional rows may be added).

Example:

```
| No. | Name  | Qty | Expiration Date | Balance |

  1     Books   10     ""               10
  2     Pens    5      ""               5
```

When I edit the first row by providing as data: `{'Name': 'Books', 'Qty': 6, 'Expiration Date': 11/2022}`. The number of rows changes:

```
| No. | Name  | Qty | Expiration Date | Balance |

  1     Books   4      ""                4
  2     Books   6      11/2022           0
  3     Pens    5      ""                5
```

Here is the structure of my code:

```
// Buttons array definition to create previous, save and next buttons in
// an Editor form
var backNext = [
    {
        text: "&lt;",
        action: function (e) {
            // On submit, find the currently selected row and select the previous one
            this.submit( function () {
            }).done( function (){
                var indexes = table.rows( {search: 'applied'} ).indexes();
                var currentIndex = table.row( {selected: true} ).index();
                var currentPosition = indexes.indexOf( currentIndex );

                if ( currentPosition > 0 ) {
                    var prev;
                    for (let i = currentPosition; i > 0; i--){
                        if(table.row(i-1).data()["Date"] === ""){
                            prev = i-1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(prev !== undefined){
                        table.row( currentIndex ).deselect();
                        table.row( indexes[ prev ] ).select();
                    }
                }
                // Trigger editing through the button
                table.button( 0 ).trigger();
            });
        }
    },
    'Save',
    {
        text: "&gt;",
        action: function (e) {
            this.submit( function() {

            }).done( function (){
                var currentIndex = table.row( {selected: true} ).index();
                var currentPosition = this.indexes.indexOf( currentIndex );
                var indexes = table.rows( {search: 'applied'} ).indexes();

                if ( currentPosition < indexes.length-1 ) {
                    var next = 0;
                    for (let i = currentPosition; i < indexes.length-1; i++){
                        if(table.row(i+1).data()["Date"] === ""){
                            next = i+1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (next !== 0){
                        table.row( currentIndex ).deselect();
                        table.row( indexes[ next ] ).select();
                    }
                }
                // Trigger editing through the button
                table.button( 0 ).trigger();
            }); 
        }
    }
];
```

what the code is supposed to do:

When I press the `next` or `previous` button, I have to go to the next/previous line, **but only when the expiry date is empty**.

In the example above, after editing line 1, the `next` button must take me to the third line by skipping the second one.

Now the problem is that Ajax is asynchronous it means that with the example provided on the site of datatables, the recovery of the indexes and the current position takes into account only the previous structure of the table. The new row is not taken into account. That's why I added the `done` method, to wait for the ajax request to be completed and the table to be redrawn, to retrieve the indexes and the current position.

But my code does not work properly. I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.submit(...).done is not a function`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: `submit()` is not an async method, so `done()` is irrelevant (as the error alludes to). If you want to perform some logic on the datatable when the data is updated you need to add an event listener to it. https://www.datatables.net/reference/event/. I'd suggest `draw` in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much I just adjusted my code and it works perfectly. But I have a little problem with the line: `var currentPosition = indexes.indexOf( currentIndex );`. This line gives me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. I am not a javascript specialist, but I have the impression that it is related to the fact that this code is not executed in the context of `this`. Can you show me a track to solve this problem?